# Java 8, IntStream BaseStream, multiple reference to index

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to do reference to INDEX multiple times

```
IntStream.range(0, number)
    .mapToObj(INDEX -> takeSubArray(someArrayBytes, (index + 1) * numBytes))
    .map(bytesNumber -> getIntegerFromBytes(bytesNumber[0], bytesNumber[1]))
    .map(theNumber -> new SomeObject(theNumber, INDEX));
```

Is it possible?

Comment: what is your requirement? please post a minimal-reproducible-example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
IntStream.range(0, number)
    .mapToObj(index -> {
        bytesNumber = takeSubArray(someArrayBytes, (index + 1) * numBytes);
        return new SomeObject(getIntegerFromBytes(bytesNumber[0], bytesNumber[1]), index);
    })
```